# Disable TableView Interaction when Keyboard Present

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have searchBar that presents the keyboard when a user taps the searchBar and disables the keyboard when the user taps outside.

However, the tap gesture interacts with the tableView content. How can I disable interaction with the tableView while the keyboard is present?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // dismiss keyboard if tapped outside of search
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("hideKeyboard"))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true //false doesn't work
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func hideKeyboard() {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent UIView when keyboard is present and remove it when keyboard is dismissed.

```
var searchBackgroundView = UIView()
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.width, tableView.frame.height))
    tableView.addSubview(searchBackgroundView)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBackgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick ideas:

1. present a transparent button over the entire scrollview instead of using the gesture recognizer, this would catch the events and block interaction with the scroll (table) view
2. store-off the gesture recognizers on the scrollview class and restore them when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by checking whether the `searchController` is `active` or not. Just like..

```
if searchController.active {
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
else {
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

**Or another way** that you choose :

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false   
}
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```